# Lights for Rixen Kaul Klickfix shopper basket

Tags: lighting, basket

I am looking for a solution to attach lights to my [Rixen Kaul Klickfix shopper basket](https://freeel.bike/en/accessories/black-shopper-basket-for-freeel-z03-ebike.html):

[image]

Any suggestions? Would [this clip](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KlickFix-Light-Clip-For-Baskets/dp/B01N486WHV) work with the basket above?

[image] [image]

Comment: Just be creative.  You could clip/tie something to the loops in the bag handle, you could use bits from a hardware store to clamp to the bag frame.  The clip you reference MIGHT work, if there is room along the rim to fit it.

Comment: The handlebars would be the normal spot for light mounts - does this bag obscure that position ?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to modify that bracket but it's a good starting point if you've got basic tools. You might, for example, have to enlarge the groove - or you might need to glue some thick rubber across it.

One thing to check on the basket itself is that that edge where you want to fit the light is rigid enough to mount on, and attached fairly stiffly to the bike. It probably is but the fabric means I can't be sure from the picture.